# Identification for Hinge-like Piece

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to follow building instructions on [Brickshelf](http://www.brickshelf.com/cgi-bin/gallery.cgi?f=547475), but I'm having some trouble finding the piece on the right in this photo:
[image: 4 pieces].

Anyone know what it is?

Comment: As Phil B said above, it is a droid body piece, exclusive to star wars, so you might want to look in the star wars section.

Comment: @SamuelL. nitpick: The droid body has graduated from the Star Wars theme some time ago, and appears in all sorts of sets besides Star Wars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is a [30375 - Torso Mechanical, Battle Droid](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=30375#T=S&C=11&O=%7B%22color%22:%2211%22%7D) in black.

[image]

It's a little difficult to identify as it is lying on its belly, and hence you do not see the characteristic single stud front of this piece.