# Identification for harness/hose/pipe + wings

Tags: set-identification

I'm still trying to follow the instructions mentioned in my last [question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/7042/4334), and I came upon this image:
[image: harness piece].

Does anybody know what piece/pieces that/those are on the right? (I know the # for the pistols.)

Also: the wings on the right:
[image: wings].
All the wings I found either had holes for pins or were too big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [30191](http://brickset.com/parts/design-30191) Strap 12 M:

[image: 30191]

This is listed as x169 on Bricklink and [Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/x169), and is also called a stretcher holder, as that was it's original use when it was first created in 1998:

[image: 6462]

Edit: It's acceptable and even preferred to post new questions to identify new parts. With that said, the wing part in your updated question is [15082 Animal Wing with Shaft](http://brickset.com/parts/design-15082):

[image: 15082]

Comment: any ideas for the wings in my updated question?

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like Brickset has better fuzzy searching, I'll have to try that next time.